# How can I program the script on my server to the receive a cname pointed to it?

Tags: php, web-applications

I am in the final stages of creating a mobile responsive customer relations management platform. Presently it is written in php as a stand-alone self-installing script.

I would like, however, to convert it to being hosted on my server where the client points their domain to my server via the use of the cname and their site is dynamically renders from my server.

Making the conversion to dynamically generate their site is not the issue. My problem lies in how to set up the script on my server to receive the incoming cname showing their domain in the address bar.

The GoMobi platform is an example of what I mean. All sites point to the same url on the GoMobi site, yet the the client's domain/subdomain is rendered.

I am familiar with how to point a cname but as stated not sure how to receive it. I have searched for the answer but the serps always return how to point and not how to receive.

Any assistance with either the solution or a link to the solution is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Pete

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] I believe.  If that's not it, its one of the predefined globals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web server sees http requests not any of the dns voodoo involved so it is just a name based virual host like the examples provided at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: thanks for the input, it pointed me in the right direction